# Why don't fluid background SVG files display correctly at all sizes?

Tags: html, css, image, svg, responsive-design

I am currently trying to use svg files instead of images for modern browsers on a new fluid site. The idea is to use an SVG as a background image on a fluid div which can then be changed on hover and we can use modernizer (or similar) to fallback to the use of img backgrounds for unsupported browsers.

In theory this is all fine however on certain browsers (particularly Firefox) the right and bottom edges of the svgs have some strange pixelation at certain sizes which doesn't happen for imgs.

So if you view http://jsfiddle.net/deshg/xuq6812g/ you can see a grid of 4 x 25% columns each with a div or img (that is 100% width). Each one has either a div with svg or img background or an img element with the svg/img as the src. If you view this in FF and make it bigger/smaller you'll see at certain sizes the degradation i'm talking about. You can also see this in the image below (the areas circled in blue are the degraded bits which you can see occurs on the svg but not the img).

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening and how to prevent it as it makes SVGs largely unusable in this way if it can't be fixed

[image: SVG vs IMG Screenshot]

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
}

.container div {
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    BACKGROUND SVG:<br>
    <div style="background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rga8anccnpyublh/svg.svg');">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    BACKGROUND IMG:<br>
    <div style="background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rb1u7l90q9ny8bh/img.png');">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    SVG IN IMG TAG:<br>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rga8anccnpyublh/svg.svg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="container">
    IMG IN IMG TAG:<br>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rb1u7l90q9ny8bh/img.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any artifacts on mac ( chrome / firefox ) or pc ( chrome / firefox ). What browser versions are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MathiasaurusRex and very strange, I'm using Firefox 31.0 on a PC (this gives the worst display anyway), what PC version of FF are you running?

Comment: It's work fine for me, but you can try with this css property `image-rendering` and adjust render of your images : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Comment: I have just tried image-rendering but none of the options have any effect unfortunately. Are you running FF 31.0 on a PC and the jsfiddle looks okay?

Comment: I have now tried this on 2 different computers and am getting the same result, does anyone have any idea why this might be? Thanks

Comment: @deshg - hopefully my answer will fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From working with vector images for years and years, when you crop them accurately, yet they need aliasing, then the crop looks odd -- flattened at the curves. So circles, text, logos, and so forth need some extra edge in the view box.  Here I've add a lot more, but you get the idea.

**DEMO with before and after: http://jsbin.com/buquw/1/edit**

ORIGINAL -- cropped accurately, but too close, because this image needs aliasing.
[image]

NEW VERSION -- you don't need this much, used to exaggerate the situation:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Christina you're a legend (sorry I didn't accept earlier I thought I had). Your solution definitely makes the degredation much less noticable although it's still not perfect, I guess we're still a way off being able to use SVGs interchangably with imgs! Thanks again